# SQL query builder in QGIS 3 doesn't display columns names

Tags: qgis, sql, query

I'm creating sql queries using QGIS 3.8 DB Manager.

The problem i'm facing is that when I write a query, I don't have any option to display the columns names :

[image]

Is there any way to display the columns names like in QGIS 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select the tables you intend to use in your query **first**, then the columns names will be displayed *(the **columns** drop down menu will be populated)* ...